# enable all touchpad functions

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, gestures

When I had been using Windows 8 my touchpad had multiple gestures:

- 2 fingers direction top-bottom = vertical revers scrolling(if I scrolled top than page have scrolled bottom);
- 2 finger direction left-right = horizontal revers scrolling
- zoom in and zoom out like smartphones with 2 fingers
- 2 finger rotation = rotate image in image viewer (+ 90 deg or -90 deg)
- place a finger in the left edge and drag it to right = change windows application, in Ubuntu I want to change the active program to left like Ctrl+Shift+Tab
- place a finger in the right edge and drag it to left = open right menu and select the option moving finger on direction top-bottom, in Ubuntu I want to change the active program to right like Alt+Tab

I succeed enable 2 finger vertical scrolling of System Setings, but I want that it do not work in revers sense. Do it exist a method to enable the rest of gestures and revers the vertical scrolling?

edit: It's a Synaptics touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional configuration app to manage your touchpad:

just install `gpointing-device-settings`

Comment: it enable only 2 fingers revers scrolling(vertical & horizontal); How work circular scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

you can install 
Synaptiks Touchpad management from the ubuntu software center.

```
kde-config-touchpad 0.8.1-1ubuntu4
```

Comment: I install it and I don't understand how use it